# Overlaying images from stream in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, resources, overlay

I'd like to overlay a number of images (PNG, same size for all, with transparency). So far, my code is as follows.

```
    bg = New Bitmap(My.Resources.blue)
    g = Graphics.FromImage(bg)

    overlay = New Bitmap(tree.Image)
    g.DrawImage(overlay, 0, 0)
```

Now, I would like to overlay one more image, but this is based on a user's input from a textbox. So, to get that image, we need to take the user's input, and get the respective resource file.

I do it as follows:

```
Dim stream As IO.Stream = Nothing    
Dim path As String = Assembly.GetName().Name.ToString() + "." + inputbox.text + ".png"
stream = Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(path)
```

And this correctly finds the image stream.

Now, I try and overlay the images:

```
    overlay = New Bitmap(stream)
    g.DrawImage(overlay, 0, 0)
```

However, this overlay doesn't seem to work.

Note that if I do something like this:

```
overlay = New Bitmap(My.Resources._5)
g.DrawImage(overlay, 0, 0)
```

The overlay works correctly.

So question is: Why is the overlay not working from the stream?

Edit:
It turns out that the overlay does actually work, but seems to overlay an enlarged image rather than the true size. Would there be any reason for this?

Comment: Check that your stream is finished downloading. In many languages and situations, trying to access information before it's "all there" can cause problems.

Comment: Have you verified that the bitmap you make from the stream is actually a correct, legitimate image, not a `null` value or something corrupted?

Comment: @Dmitri Nesteruk:
Well, the image does exist (it's there as an embedded resource), if that's what you mean.

@Moshe
I'm fairly new to using resources in VB .NET applications. How would I check to see if the stream is finished downloading?

Comment: Also, @Dmitri Nesteruk

If I do this instead:
overlay = New Bitmap(stream) 
finalpic.Image = overlay

I get the image out. So, I think this may also answer Moshe's question. The image is there and it's good to go. Only problem is that it's not getting overlayed.

Comment: After playing a bit more with the code, I found that the image from the stream gets resized when I use g.DrawImage(overlay, 0, 0). Why would this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem - I've tracked the problem to DPI of image being overlaid and DPI of image that is overlay. Check those two values, and try changing them before doing DrawImage